# Memory Leak is it?

Tags: 2007, development, performance

I have this small chunk of code and I can't understand why it's taking soo memory.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite("http://consotvo.internal.com/upi"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = mySite.OpenWeb())
            {
                //foreach (SPFile file in web.Files[0])
                //    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);

                SPFile file = web.Files[0];

                using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
                {
                    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wb in manager.WebParts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(wb.Title);


                        //wb.Dispose();
                        //manager.Web.Dispose();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is consuming **97,868 k** even after code has been executed even thought i didn't closed console window yet. my problem is that i want to open 3000 webs (different url) and make changes to a webpart ***but too much memory is being consumed***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd guess the culprit would be:

```
SPFile file = web.Files[0];
```

This will load the entire collection into memory, even though you are only after a specific file.

Use [`SPWeb.GetFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476063%28v=office.14%29.aspx) instead.

## Edit

Additionally, [SharePoint 2007 and WSS 3.0 Dispose Patterns by Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx#SPDisposeCheckID_160) provides an example of using the `SPLimitedWebPartManager`, that requires an explicit `Dispose()` call on `SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web`:

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://moss"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPFile page = web.GetFile("Source_Folder_Name/Source_Page");
        using (SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
            try
            {
                // ...
            }
            finally
            {
                webPartManager.Web.Dispose();
            }
        }
    } // SPWeb object web.Dispose() automatically called
}  // SPSite object siteCollection.Dispose() automatically called
```

Also, there is a fairly lengthy description of this issue by Bryan Napier here: [SPLimitedWebPartManager Memory Leak?](http://www.ofonesandzeros.com/2007/06/05/splimitedwebpartmanager-memory-leak/)

## Edit 2

The above `SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web` memory leak is apparently fixed in SP2010.

Comment: it reduced it to 96,720 k now, thanks but don't think it's enough, +1

Comment: when code gets into SPLimitedWebPartManager it adds 40,000 to 44,000 making it +90,000.

Comment: already tried disposing, nothing happens

Comment: I even tried disposing object in foreach loop but didn't seen any difference, however I will accept answer. thank you

Comment: One thing I would try, with the Manager.Web disposed, after you run the application, check the ULS to see if you get an entry stating that the system cleaned up an item that wasn't disposed. That way you can tell if there's a leak or not.